# Find probability mass function of random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, conditional-probability

> Given two lottery tickets, out of which one can be bought. The first lottery \$100 can be won with probability 0.1, and the price of ticket is \$10. In the second lottery, \$50 can be won with probability 0.1 and \$500 with probability 0.01. The price of ticket is \$20. To decide which ticket to buy a fair coin can be tossed. In case of head, first ticket is chosen else the second ticket. Let $X$ be random variable that denotes the net payout (taking into account price of a ticket). Find probability mass function of $X$?

I tried doing the above by using law of total probability by using the conditional probability $P(X|H)$ and $P(X|T)$ and the respective probabilities $P(H)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $P(T)=\frac{1}{2}$. So here $P(X)=P(X|H)*P(H)+P(X|T)*P(T)$. Here I assumed $P(X|H)=p$ and $P(X|T)=q$. So here $\Sigma p=1$ and $\Sigma q=1$ for the first and the second lottery ticket.

Would the expected value of $X$ be dependent on different payout or probabilities? In the above case, it is coming as average of the expected values of net payouts for each of two lotteries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the possible discrete values that random variable $X$ (net payout) can take on and what are their probabilities? For example, one can have net payout of $30$ with probability $\frac{1}{2} \times 0.1 = 0.05$. The same is true for net payout of $90$.

$p(x)$ = $\left
\{\begin{array}
{l}0.05 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x \in \{30, 90\} \\ 
... \\
...
\end{array}
\right.$

Can you complete this by finding other discrete values of $X$ and associated probabilities?

Comment: Thanks. Had a query like random variable X can take payout values from either the first lottery or second lottery. So if we have a biased coin then would expected value of X be average of expected values for the first and second lottery? Also if the respective probabilities and payout changes would there be an effect on the expected value?

Comment: Regardless of biased coin or otherwise, once you complete the pmf table, the expected value of $X$ will be sum of the product of discrete values of $X$ and associated probabilities. In this case for example, $E(X) = 0.05 \times 30 + 0.05 \times 90 + ...$.

Comment: Ok got it thanks

Comment: You are welcome. When you are done and if you want validation, let me know.

Comment: Sure. Thank you.

Comment: I am getting the values as the following:  X     -\$20 -\$10 \$30 \$90 \$480 
                                                              and p(x)0.445 0.45 0.05 0.05 0.005

Comment: Yes that's all correct. You may want to have one row in the end which says $0$ ....... otherwise. In other words probabilities for discrete values of X and for any other values of X, the probability is zero.

Comment: Thank you. Had a small doubt regarding the net payout and probabilities if they change, would the expected value change?I multiplied random variable X on both sides of the total probability equation and am getting expected value of X dependent on the probability of fair coin toss

Comment: Yes if the probabilities in pmf change, expected net payout will change. Right now the expected net payout should come to $-5$.

Comment: May be my earlier point yesterday about fair or unfair coin was not clear. The point I was trying to make is that in the end all of that would reflect in your pmf anyway.

Comment: Ok thanks but would expected value of X be average of expected values of the first and second lottery regardless of the probabilities and net payout for each lottery?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Sure. Thank you